# Ruby on Rails adds new collection to MongoDb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I wrote a method to add a new collection into an existing database `test_database`, in MongoDB, but it is not working.

I am using:

- The MongoDB driver version 2.0.4 at [MongoDB Ruby Driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/ruby/)
- Ruby 1.9
- Rails 3.2

```rb
def add_mongo_collections()
begin
  client = Mongo::Client.new([ '127.0.0.1:27017' ])
  database = Mongo::Database.new(client, 'test_database')
  collection = Mongo::Collection.new(database, 'test_collection')
  collection.create      
rescue Exception => e
  p "cannot add collection"      
end
```

After calling the method `collection.create`, an exception occurs:

```
No server is available matching preference: 
#<Mongo::ServerSelector::Primary:0x000000076adef0 @tag_sets=[], 
@options={:database=>"admin"}, 
@server_selection_timeout=30>
```

Comment: Can you include the exception message that you are getting (or some description of how you are checking that the code is not working)? Also, what version of the Ruby driver are you using? FYI: typically you would only explicitly create a collection if you want to use non-default options (eg. create a capped collection). Otherwise the collection is created implicitly when you insert data into it.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use a gem like Mongoid or so?

Comment: i just want to add new collections without data inside them